# Angular material how to position mat-sidenav top or bottom

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I am new to angular material. From angular material doc i can see it can be positioned 'start' or 'end'.

```
<div style="border:solid 1px red;">
    <mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav class="sidenav"
                     position="end" <!-- want to position top or bottom here-->
                     [opened]="sidenavOption.open"
                     [mode]="sidenavOption.mode">
            Sidenav content
        </mat-sidenav>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

I would like to position 'top' or 'bottom'

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could consider using [mat-expansion-panel](https://v8.material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) for something like a drawer opening from bottom to top.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the sidenav as the name suggests can only be present on the right (`end`) or left (`start`) side of your page. Even though the material design specifications allow a bottom drawer ([here](https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html#usage)).

As stated [here](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) there is no other property than position to specify the position other than left or right.

It seems that you would either need to make your own implementation of such a drawer -But for that you can extend from the material design classes and build upon them- or you could use a [MatBottomSheet](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview), which is almost the same, but can only be used as a kind of bottom drawer.

Comment: using MatBottomSheet is so much easier and it's exactly what is needed